# PDF form fill with PDFBox doesn't work

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, pdf-form

I have a PDF file with some form fields that I need to fill in from Java code. I use PDFBox library for this, and this code:

```
PDDocument pdfDoc = PDDocument.load("C:\\Users\\igor\\Desktop\\test.pdf");
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDoc.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
PDField field = acroForm.getField("applicationPrepaid[0].#pageSet[0].Pagina1[0].txtFirstName[0]");
if (field != null) {
    field.setValue("Milan");
} else {
    System.err.println("No field found with name:" + "applicationPrepaid[0].#pageSet[0].Pagina1[0].txtFirstName[0]");
}
pdfDoc.save("C:\\Users\\igor\\Desktop\\testout.pdf");
pdfDoc.close();
```

The PDF is not created by me, so I don't know what type of form the file uses (if I understand correctly, there are FDF and XFA forms). Since the PDF is not created by me, I used this tool http://support.persits.com/pdf/demo_formfields.asp to find out the names of the form fields, and it gave me this:

```
applicationPrepaid[0].#pageSet[0].Pagina1[0].txtFirstName[0]
```

When I use this long field name, I don't get any errors, but the resulting PDF does not contain the value I put in the field. I thought that maybe there was something wrong with the field name, so I used [Pdftk tool](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) which gave me just `txtFirstName` for the field name. But when I use just that, I get the `No field found with name: txtFirstName` error. Help?

Comment: The field name suggests that it is a XFA field. Maybe you have to address XFA fields differently in PDFBox? (I don't know the PDFBox API at all...)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well I realise this question is very old now, but I stumbled across it and thought I should post my solution.

You can find out the id's of the fields in the PDF form using PDFBox. It has a very rich API, it just unfortunately requires lots of reading to figure out what you have to do.

To get the name of the form field, you want to use `getFullyQualifiedName` which is part of the `PDField` class.

Unfortunately, you can't get all the filenames in one go (that I can tell) from the `PDAcroform` class, so you can simply create an array of the form names and then loop through each one.

e.g.

```
    // Load the pdfTemplate
    pdfTemplate = PDDocument.load(file);

    PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfTemplate.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();

    // Get field names
    List<PDField> fieldList = acroForm.getFields();

    // String the object array
    String[] fieldArray = new String[fieldList.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (PDField sField : fieldList) {
        fieldArray[i] = sField.getFullyQualifiedName();
        i++;
    }

    // Loop through each field in the array and do something
    for (String f : fieldArray) {
        PDField field = acroForm.getField(f);

        System.out.println("f is: " + f);
        if (f.contains("EXAMPLE FORM FIELD NAME")) {
            DO SOMETHING
                            String value = "example value";
            field.setValue(value);
            System.out.println("printed: " + value + " to: " + f);
        }
    }

    // Save edited file
    pdfTemplate.save(sPdfTemplate);
    pdfTemplate.close();
```

Hope this helps someone.

Cheers